# border-bottom,wrapping text

Tags: html, css, border, word-wrap

I have problem with wrapping in css. I need red border-bottom start in place with word 'somewordhere'..solution with span/other html method is not allowed here, because text is generating from CMS...what i need -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDTeK.png

Second row Intouchables is ok

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/XGRwy/384/

```
ul { text-align:center; padding: 10px; border: 2px solid green}
li { margin: 10px 0 10px; display: inline-block; border-bottom: 2px solid red;}
li a {text-decoration:none; border-left: 2px solid orange; }

<ul style="width: 150px">
   <li>
      <a href="http://some">BEGIN........END somewordhere</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="http://some">Intouchables</a>
   </li>    
</ul>
```

​

Comment: Can you wrap `BEGIN........END` in a `<span>`?

Comment: i need in css, because text is generating from CMS system

Comment: The first line should be like this? http://i.imgur.com/MwOZZ.png

Comment: It works if you put a `<br>` instead of letting it wrap, or if you give it `display:inline-block` with a set width, but none of these are very satisfying I guess.

Comment: float:left is no solution, because red line should start like here http://i.imgur.com/MwOZZ.png

Comment: here http://i.imgur.com/JWd1X.png

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/XGRwy/387/?

Answer (score 0):

I went off the image that Fabricio put up that you said is what it should look like.

I removed the left border call and put it on the 'li' and then I made the 'li' have a width of 100%.

```
ul { text-align:center; padding: 10px; border: 2px solid green; width: 150px; }
li { width: 100%; margin: 10px 0 10px; border-bottom: 2px solid red; border-left: 2px solid brown;}
li a {text-decoration:none;  }
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGRwy/389/) working example.